# How to understand Stress-Ng Test Results on Debian?

Tags: debian, cpu, stress-test

I have been troubleshooting an issue I have had with a old laptop, Acer Aspire 5745 with a Intel Core i3-370M processor. Currently running Debian with Raspbery Pi Desktop for the OS in hopes of the issue being related to software. Anyway, I ended up running stress-ng to test the processor's abilities but I can not seem to figure out if the results are good or bad. Using this specific command...

```
stress-ng --cpu 8--io 2 --timeout 30s --metrics
```

The results for the CPU were...

```
stress-ng: info: [5721] successful run completed in 30.15s

bogo ops  realtime  usr time  sys time  bogo ops/s   bogo ops/s
            (sec)     (sec)    (sec)    (real time)  (usr+sys time)
 10188    30.05     118.88     0.00      339.06      85.70
```

So how can I compare this data so that I may understand if these values reflect a good or bad result. I can not find any resources which can explain this to me.

```
stress-ng --sequential 2 --timeout 1m --metrics-brief
```

Also fun fact, tried using this command above as a second stress test and after a hour, I had to turn off the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Getting "good" or "bad" metrics arent the purpose of stress tests.  Stress tests are used to stress the system so you can see how *other* applications and hardware deal with the load.

Comment: While that may be the true purpose of stress-ng, your answer does not provide details on how to actually read the results either way. What do the numbers mean? If they don't matter, why are they provided?